# Bulk update/create in one request

Tags: django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework provide an example on how to implement bulk update.
The example shows that the update methods handles updating, creating and destroying instances.
What I fail to understand is how the new data can have an 'id' as I thought that an id/pk would be created once the object has been saved to the database. By my understanding the 2nd line should fail when new instances are in validated_data as they don't have an id.

**The example**

```
class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
    data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data} # --> shouldn't this fail if new items are in validated data?

    # Perform creations and updates.
    ret = []
    for book_id, data in data_mapping.items():
        book = book_mapping.get(book_id, None)
        if book is None:
            ret.append(self.child.create(data))
        else:
            ret.append(self.child.update(book, data))

    # Perform deletions.
    for book_id, book in book_mapping.items():
        if book_id not in data_mapping:
            book.delete()

    return ret
```

[Link to the example in Django Rest Framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the example requires the `id` to be set. You'll need a different algorithm to handle item creation without `id`

Comment: The id creation is handled by the database and not by Django.
Wouldn't it be easier to just have two dicts. One for new_data_mapping and the other for existing. This could be implemented by checking for the id attribute and if it does not exists then the item is added to new_data_mapping.

Do you have a link to information on how to implement the kind of algorithm you are suggesting?

Comment: "The id creation is handled by the database and not by Django" < semi true. It's handled by the DB *if* it is left null during save. And as for the algorithm, none is publicly available.